# Scoping rules in Java

Tags: java, syntax, braces

Can someone help me understand the scoping rules in Java?  This is clearly not valid:

```
    {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(i); // fine, of course
    }
    System.out.println(i); // syntax error
```

`i` is declared within the `{}`, and it's not available outside.  So what about this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.println(i); // fine, of course
    }
    System.out.println(i);  // syntax error, same as above.
```

I'm surprised at the syntax error here. `i` is declared in the outer scope yet it is not available later on.  Is it bound to the inner block scope by some special rule for `for` loops?  Are there other scenarios where this can happen?

Comment: There is a difference between the "bare" `{}` and `{}` associated with *any other keywords or grammar production* -- that is, it must be viewed in the context of the grammar even if a number of cases have similar semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

think of for loop actually represented like this:

```
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    // your code
    i ++
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is supported by the JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#35529) "If the ForInit code is a local variable declaration, it is executed as if it were a local variable declaration statement appearing in a block. "

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it bound to the inner block scope by some special rule for for loops?*

Yes, this is exactly the case.

There's obviously the local variable declaration:

```
class Some { 
   public void x( int i ) { 
    System.out.println( i ); // valid 
   }
   int j = i; // not valid 
}
```

See also:

- [Scope of a Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#103228)
- [Scope of Local Variable Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.4.2)

From the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

It's the defined behavior of the `for` loop in Java.

```
class ForDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args){
          for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
               System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
          }
     }
}
```

> Notice how the code declares a
>   variable within the initialization
>   expression. The scope of this variable
>   extends from its declaration to the
>   end of the block governed by the for
>   statement, so it can be used in the
>   termination and increment expressions
>   as well. If the variable that controls
>   a for statement is not needed outside
>   of the loop, it's best to declare the
>   variable in the initialization
>   expression. The names i, j, and k are
>   often used to control for loops;
>   declaring them within the
>   initialization expression limits their
>   life span and reduces errors.

Source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html